# Idiomatic composition of $http and $httpBackend in AngularJS 1.2.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have an AngularJS/Jasmine unit test that works fine with AngularJS 1.0.7, but doesn't work in Angular 1.2.2:

**servicesSpec.js**

```
describe('services', function() {
    beforeEach(module('workPadApp'));

    describe('taskGateway', function() {
        var sut;
        beforeEach(inject(function(taskGateway) {
            sut = taskGateway;
        }));

        describe('saving a task', function() {
            it('GETs correctly', inject(function($httpBackend) {
                $httpBackend.expectGET('/').respond({ foo : 'bar' });
                sut.createTask({ taskRef : 'baz' });
                $httpBackend.flush();
            }))
        })
    })
})
```

**app.js**

```
var workPadApp = angular.module('workPadApp', ['workPadApp.services']);
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('workPadApp.services', []).

  factory('taskGateway', function($http, $q) {
    return {
      createTask : function(task) {
        $http.get('/')
          .success(function(response) {
            console.log('success');
          })
          .error(function(response) {
            console.log('error');
          });
      }
    }
  });
```

**Expected result**

When I run this with Karma using AngularJS 1.0.7, all is good:

> LOG: 'success'
>
> Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.179 secs / 0.03 secs)

**Actual result**

However, when I run it with AngularJS 1.2.2, I get this output:

> Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 7) services taskGateway saving a task GETs correctly FAILED
>
> ```
>    Error: No pending request to flush !
>
>        at Error (native)
>        at Function.$httpBackend.flush (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1195:34)
>        at null.<anonymous> (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/unit/servicesSpec.js:91:18)
>        at Object.invoke (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/app/lib/angular.js:3641:28)
>        at workFn (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1778:20)
>    Error: Declaration Location
>        at window.jasmine.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1764:25)
>        at null.<anonymous> (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/unit/servicesSpec.js:72:26)
>        at null.<anonymous> (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/unit/servicesSpec.js:62:3)
>        at null.<anonymous> (c:/Users/Mark/Documents/Grean/HHM/Src/HHMFrontend/test/unit/servicesSpec.js:8:2)
> ```
>
> Chrome 33.0.1750 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.349 secs / 0.133 secs)

I've looked at the [documentation for $httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend), and the example there uses a much more imperative style of setup using an `$injector` service.

That surprises me, since the declarative style that worked in version 1.0.7 is much terser. Is this really the only correct way going forward, or am I missing something?

Comment: The above test, as-is, passed on 1.2.2 (as well as 1.2.6). To see it fail (and make sure that it wasn't a False Positive) I changed the `$http.get('/')` to `$http.get('/foo')`, it failed, and then I changed it again to `$http.get('/')` where it passed. Do all angular-* modules in the project have the same version? (FWIW, the project that I've run the repro uses: angular -resource -cookies -sanitize -route -mocks and -scenario.)

Comment: OMG, that was it! I had an older version of angular-mocks.js. Updating it to the same version resolved the issue :$ Please post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773839/idiomatic-composition-of-http-and-httpbackend-in-angularjs-1-2-2#comment34728066_22773839) the relevant `angular-*` modules must be the [same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773839/idiomatic-composition-of-http-and-httpbackend-in-angularjs-1-2-2#comment34726607_22773839).

In this example, `angular.js` and `angular-mocks.js` had to be the same version, 1.2.2.